# Layers: expected type: JSONArray, found: String

Tags: python, arrays, json, amazon-web-services, lambda

I have created a lambda layer using cloudformation template

```
        "MyLayer": {
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion",
            "Properties": {
                "CompatibleRuntimes": [
                    "python3.9"
                ],
                "Content": {
                    "S3Bucket": "newtest-45",
                    "S3Key": "mypackage.zip"
                },
                "Description": "My layer",
                "LayerName": "my-layer"
            }
        },
```

Trying to associate this Lambda Layer to the Lambda Function by referencing it in the Properties block like this

```
                "Layers": {
                    "Ref": "MyLayer"
                },
```

But i am getting this error while running the cloudformation stack

Layers: expected type: JSONArray, found: String

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyQJ8.png)

Can you please help resolve this error that i am facing, tried all different options and answers that were available but none worked.

Comment: I think your `Layers` expects an array, so maybe try this: `"Layers": [{"Ref": "MyLayer"}]`

Answer (score 2):

After verifying in my AWS account for a Cloud Formation YAML using a lambda Layer,

your issue, is that, Layers expects an Array:

```yaml
functionID:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    ...
      Handler: function.handler
      Layers:
        - arn:aws:lambda:region:012345678910:layer:layer1:versionN
        - arn:aws:lambda:region:012345678910:layer:layer2:versionM
      MemorySize: 256
      Runtime: python3.9
      Timeout: 900
```

so, in JSON: `"Layers": [{"Ref": "MyLayer"}]`

I invite you to look through the CDK if you can in your environment, it would take care of these kind of issues: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with-cdk-python.html